# Add elements from one list to another C#

Tags: c#

What is the simplest way to add elements of one list to another?

For example, I have two lists:

List A which contains x items
List B which contains y items.

I want to add elements of B to A so that A now contains X+Y items. I know this can done using a loop but is there a built in method for this? Or any other technique?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Your question describes the [List.AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc.aspx) method, which copies all the elements of its argument into the list object on which it is called.

As an example, the snippet

```
List<int> listA = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
List<int> listB = Enumerable.Range(11, 10).ToList();
Console.WriteLine("Old listA: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", listA));
Console.WriteLine("Old listB: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", listB));
listA.AddRange(listB);
Console.WriteLine("New listA: [{0}]", string.Join(", ", listA));
```

prints

```
Old listA: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Old listB: [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
New listA: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

showing that all the elements of `listB` were added to `listA` in the `AddRange` call.

Answer (score 10):

To join two lists, you can do

```
listA.AddRange(listB); // listA will contain x+y items
```

or

```
// listC contains x+y items, listA and listB are unchanged.
var listC = listA.Concat(listB);
```

You could use the latter to reassign `listA` instead:

```
listA = listA.Concat(listB).ToList();
```

but there isn't any particular advantage to that over `AddRange` if you're okay with modifying one of the original lists in the first place.