# How to add elements from 2 lists to the third?

Tags: c#, list

I created 3 lists of the same type `int` and gave the first two a set limit of 5 elements and for the final 10 elements.
I then took the input from the user for the first two lists.
This is where I got stuck trying to add all user inputted elements into the third list. I also originally wanted the third list to display those elements in one line.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> list1 = new List<int>(5);
            List<int> list2 = new List<int>(5);
            List<int> list3 = new List<int>(10);

            Console.WriteLine ("Enter 5 whole numbers into the first list.");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                string input;
                int number;

                do
                {
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (!int.TryParse(input, out number));

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Enter 5 whole numbers into the second list.");
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                string input;
                int number;

                do
                {
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (!int.TryParse(input, out number));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Members of the first and second list are:");
            list3.AddRange(list1);             // nothing
            list3.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);  // nothing   
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Just a question, what is the purpose of having 3 lists if in the end you gonna merge list 1 and 2 into list 3? why not have a single list, adding all elements to? Or is this an excercise on how to merge 2 lists ?

Comment: are you aware that at _no point_ you are doing something with your parsed number? like.. adding it to a list? adding your list1 to list3 works - it's just that you _leave list1 empty_.

Comment: You don't add anything to `list1` and `list2`: `list1.Add(number);`, `list2.Add(number);`

Comment: @Tomek It's my homework assignment.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Holy Moly, I didn't even realize that. Thanks

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I will give it a go.

Comment: OK. then as the other 2 pointed out, you actually need to add your input to the list.  Also doing ```new List<int>(5)``` doesn't limit the list to 5 elements ... it is more of an optimising process internally ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add elements from one list to another C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13467034/add-elements-from-one-list-to-another-c-sharp)

Comment: Thank you, guys. This solved it. I forgot to add `list1.Add(number);` and `list2.Add(number);` in my `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

The *immediate* problem is that you don't add anything into `list1` and `list2`.
The deep reason, IMHO, is that your routine *too complex*: adding items it two lists
followed by list manipulation in a single routine.

Let's *extract method* for adding items into lists:

```
  private static List<int> CreateAndFillList(string caption, int count) {
    List<int> result = new List<int>(count);

    Console.WriteLine(caption);  

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Please, enter item #{i + 1}:");

        if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int item)) {
          result.Add(item); 

          break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Integer value is expected. Please, try again.");
      }
    }

    return result;        
  }
```

Then you can put

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  List<int> list1 = CreateAndFillList("Enter 5 whole numbers into the first list.", 5);
  List<int> list2 = CreateAndFillList("Enter 5 whole numbers into the second list.", 5);

  List<int> list3 = new List<int>(list1.Count + list2.Count);

  list3.AddRange(list1);
  list3.AddRange(list2);   
    
  foreach(var item in list3)
    Console.WriteLine(item);

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```